# How to get data from CSV file in Python?

Tags: python

I am using csv.reader to read file but it giving me whole file.

```
file_data = self.request.get('file_in');
file_Reader = csv.reader( file_data );
for fields in file_Reader:
```

I want one line at a time and separate data from that line.

```
ex: filedata = name,sal,dept
               x,12000,it
o\p=
name
sal
dept
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to pass a string of data directly to csv.reader().  It's expecting an iterable object like a list or filehandle.  The docs for the [csv module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) mention this. So you probably want to split the string along newlines before passing it to csv.reader.

```
import csv
file_data = self.request.get('file_in')
file_data_list = file_data.split('\n')
file_Reader = csv.reader(file_data_list)
for fields in file_Reader:
    print row
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This just prints the row. How do we get each individual value out, one for one? Working code example?

Answer (score 2):

This

```
>>> import csv
>>> spamReader = csv.reader(open('eggs.csv'), delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
>>> for row in spamReader:
...     print ', '.join(row)
Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Baked Beans
Spam, Lovely Spam, Wonderful Spam
```

Was taken from [the manual](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html)

Hope that helps...

Comment: it is giving me whole file in a single line

Comment: My point is that by the time the code reaches the print line, row should be a list of the items in a specific row of your csv. Is this not what you're seeing?

Comment: This prints the values of the row. How do I say value1=1stvalue,value2=2ndvalue, etc working code?

Comment: Each row is a list, so if you wanted the first value, you would use row[0] to access that.

Answer (score 1):

Why not do it manually?

```
for line in fd:
        foo, bar, baz = line.split(";")
```

Comment: That wouldn't handle things like quotes correctly though, would it - which would be needed if the data in the csv could, in itself, contain commas...

Comment: +1 for the hint. This is a common speed-vs-comfort trade-off.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the delimiter used is ",", I have mapped the data into x,y variables

```
import csv
x = []
y=  []
with open('FileName.csv','r') as csvfile:
    plot=csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=',')
for row in plot:
    x.append(int(row[0])) 
    y.append(int(row[1]))

plt.bar(x,y,label='name')
```